# Start a new activity

Tags: c#, android, variables, android-activity, xamarin

I am using Xamarin I am wanting to start a new activity that is called AutoLinkActivity.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text.Util;

namespace TestTextViewAutoLink
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestTextViewAutoLink", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, AutoLinkActivity);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The build error that I am getting is:

> 'TestTextViewAutoLink.AutoLinkActivity' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

May I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
  Intent intent= new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(AutoLinkActivity));
```

the second parameter has to be the type of the activity class, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
typeof(NameofyourActivity)
```

Try this if you don't want use intent and start it directly:

```
 protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
 {            
     StartActivity(typeof(AutoLinkActivity));
 }
```