# How do I create a new android activity with xamarin and f#?

Tags: xamarin, android-intent, f#, xamarin.android

I tried this:

```
let intent = new Intent(this, typeof<SettingsActivity>)
this.StartActivity(intent)
```

But it gave me an error.

> An overload for method intent can not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. Candidates: Intent (packageContext: Context, cls: Java.Lang.Class) : unit, Intent(packageContext: Context, type: Type) : unit

I cannot figure out how to solve this error. Please help. Thx.

Update: I changed typeof to typedef of and changed this to this.ActivityContext, but in says SettingsActivity not found. Here is my settings activity file:

```
namespace Math

[<Activity (Label = "SettingsActivity")>]
type SettingsActivity () =
  inherit Activity()

  override this.OnCreate(bundle) =
    base.OnCreate (bundle)
    // Create your application here

    this.SetContentView(Resources.Layout.Settings)
```

I have the same namespace declaration at the beginning of both files.
The error probably occurs, because f# cannot find the class SettingsActivity.

Comment: What is the type of `this`? Can you try casting that to `Context` using `this :> Context` ?

Comment: Looking at this C# question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086751/start-a-new-activity, perhaps you need something like `Intent(this.ApplicationContex, typeof<SettingsActivity>)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code looks exactly like you posted then the issue is

```
typeof<SettingsActivity>
```

you should use type**def**of instead:

```
let intent = new Intent(this, typedefof<SettingsActivity>)
this.StartActivity(intent)
```

In addition to that make sure the current class is actually "this", i.e. method where you are you using this code is defining reference to current class as "this"

Comment: I tried using typedefof, and I think that is good, but it still doesn't work because it says SettingsActivity not found.

Comment: Make sure file containing SettinggsActivity is higher than the file that contains code to call the activity. Checkout https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/ for more details

Comment: That is my problem, but how do you make f# process the SettingsActivity class first, and then process the MainActivity class without having to put them into a single file.

Comment: If your MainActivity in the Activity attribute has MainLauncherActivity=true then you do not need to have MainActivity before SettingsActivity. Or do you have a cyclic dependency between MainActivity and SettingsActivity? If yes then this is something that F# is designed to defeat. Preferred way would be go back to drawing board and figure out how they can interact without needing reference each other. "Workaround" way would be declare them in one file using "with" keyword (I don't think that by just having them in one file would do the trick).

Comment: Check out few suggestions on how to deal with cyclic dependencies https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/ If you are new to F# I would recommend reading articles on that site -- it helped me a lot when I was just starting up with the language.

Comment: It was not cyclicly dependent, so I figured out that alt + up arrow can move it up in the solution, and now that it is above MainActivity it works. Thanks.